# Proving an identity regarding probabilty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, probability, linear-algebra

The postulate says: the probabilty of getting the result $a$ for measuring an observable $A$ on a system in the state $|\psi\rangle$ is $$p(a, A, \psi)=||P_a|\psi\rangle||^2,$$ where $P_a$ is an eigenprojector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$.

I've managed to prove that $$p(a, A, \psi)=\langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle,$$ since  $$||P_a|\psi\rangle||^2=\langle\psi|P_a^2|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle$$ (by the definition of projector), but i'm completely stuck with proving the following identity

$$p(a, A, \psi)=\textrm{Tr } P_a |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|,$$

and don't even know where to begin. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you illustrated these quantities with simple matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to try and just give you a hint since this is probably a homework problem... but since other commenters are just giving answers theres a simple path to the solution.

$\text{Tr }[P_a|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|] = \text{Tr}\left[P_a\left(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\right)^2\right]$ by the definition of projectors
$\text{Tr }[P_a|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|] = \text{Tr}\left[|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\right]$ by cyclic property of trace
$\text{Tr }[P_a|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|] = \langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle\text{Tr}\left[|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\right]$ noting that $\langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle$ is a scalar

$\text{Tr }[P_a|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|] = \langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle$ noting that $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ is a rank one projector

Answer (score 2):

1. Use definition of trace: $\text{Tr} P_a | \psi \rangle \langle \psi| = \sum_n \langle n|P_a |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|n\rangle$ where $\{ |n\rangle \}$ is *any* an orthonormal basis set
2. $\langle n|P_a |\psi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi|n\rangle$ are complex numbers, so use commutativty of multiplication to swap them, $\sum_n \langle n|P_a |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|n\rangle = \sum_n \langle \psi|n\rangle \langle n|P_a |\psi\rangle $
3. Use the fact that $\sum_n |n\rangle \langle n| = 1$ is the resolution of the identity to finally get $ \sum_n \langle \psi|n\rangle \langle n|P_a |\psi\rangle =  \langle \psi| \sum_n|n\rangle \langle n|P_a |\psi\rangle= \langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle $. Done.

More simply, we can just note that we can construct a particular valid orthonormal basis set with the first vector being $|\psi \rangle$. All other vectors are necessarily orthogonal to it. I.e. in (1) let $|n\rangle = |\psi\rangle$ for $n=1$, then $\langle \psi |n\rangle = 0$ for $n \geq 2$. We are then done from the definition.